# Test-Path on Registry path return different values

Tags: powershell, registry

Summary: Why does `Test-Path` return different values?

This is a script. Want to check whether the Registry path is exist.

```
$regpath = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\regpath.txt
foreach ($rp in $regpath) {
    $testkey = Test-Path "$rp"
    Write-Host $testkey
    if (!$testkey) {
        Write-Host "Does not exists == $rp"
    }
}
```

These are two examples of a Registry path to be checked.

- Example 1:

  ```
  $regpath  = "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168"
  ```
- Example 2:

  ```
  $regpath = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\regpath.txt
  ## this is sample entry of regpath.txt
  "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168"
  ```

The results are different. Using example 1 the value of `Test-Path is TRUE:

```
PS C:\temp> foreach ($rp in $regpath) {
>>     $testkey = Test-Path "$rp"
>>     Write-Host $testkey
>>     if (!$testkey) {
>>         Write-Host "Does not exists == $rp"
>>     }
>> }
>>
True
```

Using example 2 (from file) the value of `Test-Path` is FALSE:

```
PS C:\temp> foreach ($rp in $regpath) {
>>     $testkey = Test-Path "$rp"
>>     Write-Host $testkey
>>     if (!$testkey) {
>>         Write-Host "Does not exists == $rp"
>>     }
>> }
>>
False
Does not exists == "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control    \SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168"
False
Does not exists == "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\PKCS"
```

Comment: `"` is not part of string literal value. Thus you `$regpath` in *example 1* and *example 2* have different values.

Comment: When you assign a string literal "foo" to a variable the variable has the value `foo` (without the quotes), but when you read a string with quotes from a file and assign that to a variable then the quotes become part of the string, as if you had assigned a literal ``$v = '"foo"'`` or ``$v = "`"foo`""``.